# WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist, but is in installed

Tags: php, laravel

I run Ubuntu 16.04 and am trying to install *mcrypt*.
I can see it in my `info.php`.

I have followed this steps:

**1. Install php7.0-mcrypt**

`sudo apt install php7.0-mcrypt`

**2.Create symbolic link to php7.0-mcrypt**

`sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/`

**3.Enable mcrypt extension**

`sudo phpenmod mcrypt`

And when I enable I get this:

```
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
```

But I don't use 7.2, I use 7.0 and I have the mcrypt ini file in `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available`.

Comment: install mycrype extentio for php 7.2

Comment: How do i install mcrypt into php7.2

Answer (score 0):

The warning reports PHP version 7.2, so that's what is apparently running.

Are you sure you are running PHP-7.0? What does `php -v` returns?

I suspect you have multiple version of PHP installed on the system.

Try to run `sudo update-alternatives --config php` and choose the version that you want to work on.
That should fix it.